# Querying an XML document which has multiple elements with same name and with different attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an`XML Document` which has several elements with same name and different attribute values and I am querying to get the data from the document to an array

```
 foreach (var trade in doc.Descendants("Trd"))
            {
                var RptSide = trade.Element("RptSide");
 sellerAccount = RptSide.Elements("Pty")
                        .Where(pty => pty.Attribute("Src").Value == "C")
                        .Select(pty => pty.Attribute("ID").Value)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

my XML is as follows

```
<Trd>      
      <RptSide  Side="1">
        <Pty R="1" ID="666">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="4" ID="666">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="7" ID="ABC">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="21" ID="CCC">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="22" ID="NY">
        </Pty>
        **<Pty R="24" Src="C" ID="666ID">**
          <Sub Typ="26" ID="1">
          </Sub>
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="24" Src="H" ID="A-62370">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="30" ID="apm">
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="36" ID="testausto">
          <Sub Typ="9" ID="Addo Ace">
          </Sub>
        </Pty>  
      </RptSide>
    </Trd>
```

From the above XML, I am expecting the `ID` of fifth `Pty` Element Where `Attribute Src="C"` that is `666ID` to be stored in `sellerAccount` but it is considering only the first Pty element which has no `Src` Attribute in it may be because of the use of `FirstOrDefault()`.

**Exception**:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestXM.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But when I changed my code to below it just worked fine

```
sellerAccount = RptSide.Elements("Pty")
                        .Where(pty => pty.Attribute("R").Value == "24")
                        .Select(pty => pty.Attribute("ID").Value)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

**May I know the correct way to query the doc to look for `Pty` element which has `Src` attribute?**

Comment: I think you'd just get an exception when you try to do this. `.Attribute` will return null when there is no such attribute, as is the case with the first 4 `Pty` elements. If you try to index `Value` on a null, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Well I got the exception as you said but not for all the elements but just when I tried to use `Src`. It worked fine when I used `R="24"`. I have edited my question and added exception and some code using `R="24"`

Comment: @Asad. I was just looking to find `Pty` element which has `Src` attribute which is equal to "C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to null check the `Src` attribute result before you call `.Value` on it to avoid the `NullReferenceException`.

For example,

```
var sellerAccount = RptSide.Elements("Pty")
            .Where(pty => pty.Attribute("Src") != null && pty.Attribute("Src").Value.Equals("C"))
            .Select(pty => pty.Attribute("ID").Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, alternatively, (with a`using System.Xml.XPath;`),

```
var sellerAccount = doc.XPathSelectElement("//*[@Src='C']").Attribute("ID").Value;
```